# Created nested / child pages HTML

Tags: html, relationship, parent-child, directory-structure

I'm building a fairly simple HTML/PHP website with about 40 pages, and I am using an htaccess rewrite to create a "faux" subdirectory folder named /support, so that url's for the "child" pages look like /support/info1, /support/info2, etc., even though they are actually uploaded to the root directory.

My line looks like:

RewriteRule ^support/(.+)$ $1 [NC,L]

However, now both url addresses are functional - that is, both /info1 and /support/info1 are pulling up the same page, which I worry will cause the web browsers confusion. What would be the best way to handle this? Is there a way to rewrite such that only one url address is functional? Or can that just be clarified through the canonical tag?

Comment: You would need to do that via [rewrite rules](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/) on the web server. How you would accomplish it would be determined by the web server you are running.

Comment: Wordpress is a CMS and really (really) has no impact on something being slow/fast since is rendered server-side. Regarding the tree structure you don't need files in folders - but you need a tree anyways.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking I might be able to define something in the .htaccess file? How would I define a tree?

Comment: What's your objection to using subfolders? Is it possible for you to `wget`/`curl` the "certain key pages" and just drop that file structure onto your new web server?

Comment: I don't want to use subfolders because it adds complication w/ link references, such as the site header and footer, which I'm pulling in via PHP, and other dynamic image & link references. Also, because I need the page /support to have content as well as its sub/child pages, and I can't seem to do that without creating it as an index.php file within the /support folder, which seems very confusing. I wouldn't think multiple files named "index" on the server is the ideal way to do it. (I know these are probably all super basic issues, but I've only ever worked on CMS and SaaS platforms to date.)